# Vue Router - Emit from child to parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I am working on a VueJS Component which switches the child component when it reaches a certain state. The parent component is a VueJS Router page. I saw that listeners should be put in the `router-view` component, but it doesn't work. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Child component (the part that emits):

```
if(this.currentQuestion == this.questionList.length) {
        console.log('will emit');
        this.$emit('on-quiz-finished');
      }
```

App.vue

```
<router-view @on-quiz-finished="quizFinished" />
```

Parent component

```
quizFinished: function() {
  console.log('it entered');
  this.isQuizFinished = true;
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to useJavascript's naming convention for methods and use camelCase? on-quiz-finished to onQuizFinished

Comment: @CássioMorales it doesn't work still, and besides vue recommends that $emit events be in kebab case

Comment: Hi I just ended up implementing Vuex in my application to make it simpler.

Comment: Ok. Good luck!!